# Could not get JDBC Connection Issue Coming

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, console-application

I am working with one web service. I have successfully consumed on my local system. I am using that service in the console application in asp.net/c#. I am getting one error related to that service.

"Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Connection reset"

This issue is not coming continuously. Coming three or four times a day.

Comment: JDBC is Java based. Is there any reason why you are choosing to use a JDBC connector rather then an ODBC one?

Comment: I am not using. My client provides me a web service link. and I have just consumed it in my code. I can access all functions. Sometimes its throwing JDBC connection issue.

Comment: How could I know the web service is created in java or c#?

Comment: Is this error coming back from the web service link you are calling or happening on your side?
Using JDBC is Java based so usually means that application is in Java. If you aren't sure about JDBC there is plenty of information out there. here is one place to start: https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/jdbc/index.html

Comment: Yes, coming from web service.